# How does smoothing in scipy RBFInterpolator work?

Tags: python, scipy, interpolation, approximation

I want to approximate scattered 2D data onto a regular grid with slightly bigger dimensions than the surrounding box of scattered data in Python.

My reference is the behavior of the R package mba.

I tried out SmoothBivariateSpline. In the inner area the results with kx and ky set to 5 and default smoothing came near to the R implementation. However, the approximated values near to the border are going crazy. That is not the case for the R function.

The RBFInterpolator looks comparable too with kernel 'linear'. However, the smoothing values I need to get propper smoothing go up in the 10^4 region.

I would like to unterstand how that smoothing works and find a good method to set default on various input.

Edit: I tried out to scale down the dimensions of x and y. To get same results I had to scale down the smoothing factor too. I guess now the smoothing factor is something like a radius for a smoothing range.